# R retriculate execute python code direct from within R code

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to use `retriculate` to run python code from R. This works, for example I can run:

```
library(retriculate)
py_run_file("mypyfile.py")
```

where the `mypyfile.py` contains:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({a:[1,2], b:[3,4]})
df.to_csv(mypythongenerateddata.csv)
```

to keep things easier I would prefer to just place these three lines of python code in the R script directly, as opposed to sourcing the python script. The documentation seems to suggest using a markdownfile, which I am not to fond off. [enter link description here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/#python-repl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `py_run_string`:

```r
library(reticulate)

py_run_string("
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
df.to_csv('mypythongenerateddata.csv')")

py$df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 3
#> 2 2 4
```